# Python yaml generate few values in quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I am using the `yaml` module in my Python script to generate a YAML file. The following is an example:

```
import yaml
class MyDumper(yaml.Dumper):

    def increase_indent(self, flow=False, indentless=False):
        return super(MyDumper, self).increase_indent(flow, False)

foo = {
    'instance_type': 'test',
    'hostname': "\"testhost\"",
    'name': 'foo',
    'my_list': [
        {'foo': 'test', 'bar': 'test2'},
        {'foo': 'test3', 'bar': 'test4'}],
    'hello': 'world',
}

print yaml.dump(foo, Dumper=MyDumper, default_flow_style=False)
```

Output:

```
hello: world
hostname: '"testhost"'
instance_type: test
my_list:
  - bar: test2
    foo: test
  - bar: test4
    foo: test3
name: foo
```

In above  output  hostname value has single and double quotes, I want  only double quotes.

Expected output:

```
hello: world
hostname: "testhost"
instance_type: test
my_list:
  - bar: test2
    foo: test
  - bar: test4
    foo: test3
name: foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot force quotes in YAML by quoting parts of your data as you do. As
the quotes force the dumper to apply quoting to the scalar (i.e. can no longer
use plain scalars as for the other string values in your yaml file).

You need to make a type that is dumped with quotes. Most easily that
is done using `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that
enhanced version of PyYAML, supporting YAML 1.2, support round-trip
preservation of comments and quotes etc).

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString as dq


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)

foo = {
    'instance_type': 'test',
    'hostname': dq("testhost"),
    'name': 'foo',
    'my_list': [
        {'foo': 'test', 'bar': 'test2'},
        {'foo': 'test3', 'bar': 'test4'}],
    'hello': 'world',
}


yaml.dump(foo, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
instance_type: test
hostname: "testhost"
name: foo
my_list:
  - foo: test
    bar: test2
  - foo: test3
    bar: test4
hello: world
```

You can also easily load that output and dump it generating exactly same ouput:

```
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO

buf = StringIO()
yaml.dump(foo, buf)

yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(buf.getvalue())
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you insist doing it through PyYAML, you can declare your own *forced quotation* type and add its representer:

```
import yaml

class MyDumper(yaml.Dumper):  # your force-indent dumper

    def increase_indent(self, flow=False, indentless=False):
        return super(MyDumper, self).increase_indent(flow, False)

class QuotedString(str):  # just subclass the built-in str
    pass

def quoted_scalar(dumper, data):  # a representer to force quotations on scalars
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='"')

# add the QuotedString custom type with a forced quotation representer to your dumper
MyDumper.add_representer(QuotedString, quoted_scalar)

foo = {
    'instance_type': 'test',
    'hostname': QuotedString('testhost'),  # here's the 'magic'
    'name': 'foo',
    'my_list': [
        {'foo': 'test', 'bar': 'test2'},
        {'foo': 'test3', 'bar': 'test4'}],
    'hello': 'world',
}

print(yaml.dump(foo, Dumper=MyDumper, default_flow_style=False))
```

Which will give you:

```
hello: world
hostname: "testhost"
instance_type: test
my_list:
  - bar: test2
    foo: test
  - bar: test4
    foo: test3
name: foo
```

Disclaimer: Given the choice, I also prefer [Anthon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307905/anthon)'s [`ruamel.yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module for my YAML needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting doubled quotes because that is what your input data has. This line:

```
'hostname': "\"testhost\"",
```

says you want `hosthame` to have as a value a 10-character string beginning and ending with `"`, and so that is what you are seeing in yaml. This string with escaped double quotes `"\"testhost\""` and the yaml version `'"testhost"'` are two different source code representations of the same data. You only need doubled quotes around a string in yaml if you want to embed special characters (like `\n` for newline) in it. But `yaml.dump()` will take care of that for you.

Comment: This is a very strange way of saying that plain scalars in YAML cannot start with a double quote and therefore are quoted (which is what the YAML standard indicates is the cause). You also don't provide a way to get the output the OP wants (even though no quotes are necessary).

Comment: I was trying to explain to the OP that he probably did not need to direct `yaml.dump()` in the way he appears to be doing. And also without using yaml-specific terminology that he might very well not understand.

Comment: Of course he needs that: "I want only double quotes". You can be sure that the  OP already is aware of how to get no quotes given the example in question